# Inserting multiple textbox data into an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I want to write a program that saves the text in textbox to an Excel file using a loop because I want to insert multiple text into Excel. I found codes but it only overwrites data in cells. I want the program to find the last row and insert new data into the next row. I'm stuck here, please someone help me how to do that in c#.

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "FirstName";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "LastName";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "JobTitle";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Address";

for (int i=2; i<=6; i++)
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = textBox1.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = textBox2.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = textBox3.Text;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = textBox4.Text;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop? The above code will write to cells in a loop. Shouldn't you be putting the above code in say a button click and then simply write to the last row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned that you don't need to use a loop. See this example

Let's say your form looks like this.

[image]

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //~~> Open File
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

            xlexcel.Visible = true;

            // Open a File
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\MyFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "FirstName";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "LastName";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "JobTitle";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Address";
        }

        //~~> Add Data
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = textBox1.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = textBox2.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = textBox3.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = textBox4.Text;
        }

        //~~> Once done close and quit Excel
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

Range object is a part of worksheet object. So you shouldn't be getting any errors there. And Like I mentioned above, the code is tried and tested.

[image]

**MORE FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

The above code was tested on VS 2010 Ultimate. If you have VS 2008 then replace the line

```
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count,
               1].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;
```

with

```
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
                                      "*",
                                      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1],
                                      Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                                      Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                      Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                      Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                                      misValue,
                                      misValue,
                                      misValue
                                      ).Row + 1 ;
```

Comment: `xactly i wntd same thng...thnx bro.... –  user2877742 23 secs ago` I thought so :)

Comment: getting a problem in the above code regarding :-

Property, indexer, or event 'Range' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.get_Range(object, object)'

wt shld b needed to do...??

Comment: in this line:-

int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;

Comment: @SiddharthRout: How do you get xlWorkSheet.Range for exel worksheet object? I don't see Range option for Excel worksheet (interop).

Comment: @Sangram: Because I know `Range` is a part of `xlWorkSheet` like I know `xlWorkSheet` is a part of `xlexcel` Please note that the above code is tired and tested. I am surprised that you are not getting that in intellisense. Updating my above post with a screenshot

Comment: @SiddharthRout :This is what i see http://i.imm.io/1is2y.png  Just figured out the reason. You are probably using .net framework 4. .net 3.5 doesn't have such option.

Comment: @Sangram: which VS version are you using?

Comment: int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" + xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;



Property, indexer, or event 'Range' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.get_Range(object, object)'

Comment: @Akk: Which VS version are you using as well?

Comment: Ah! I have not worked with 2008 for a very long time now. I have VS 2010 ultimate.

Comment: Let me remote into a pc of a friend who has 2008. will post back shortly

Comment: @akk: Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: @Akk: Also test this for me.. What do you get? `int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;` Replace this line with the other line

Comment: error:-

'object' does not contain a definition for 'End' and no extension method 'End' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Damn VS 2008! LOL. At lease the Range object problem is now solved... let me do few more tests.

Comment: @akk: Check the updated post. See `MORE FOLLOWUP (From Comments)` in the above post.

Comment: @siddhrth....d prblm is solved bro....jst 1 thng wen i open the xcelfile and write the textbox values ......it ss\uccsflly appnds inside the xcel file bt aftr dat the zcel file demands a differnt name to b saved  wd.....for eg;- i hd excel.xls file bt aftr appending txtbx values inside excel.xls file.....a window opens and demands 2 b svd wd a diffrnt name other than excel.xls file...

Comment: i jst wnt d same file to b rewritten wd values evrytime i insert...@siddhrth

Comment: @akk: Yes that is because I was opening the file in readonly mode for testing. See the line `xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\MyFile.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);` Change the paramenter for readonly.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @Sangram: Hope it is sorted for you as well?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes definitely. I was really lost when i realized i didn't have Worksheet.Range property :D

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern is to find the `last used row` in your excel.

For that you can use

```
 Excel.Range usedRange = xlWorkSheet .UsedRange;
 Excel.Range _lastCell= usedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell,  
 Type.Missing);

  int _lastRow= lastCell.Row; // Gives you the last used row in your Excel sheet
  int _lastCol = lastCell.Column; // Give you the last used column



 _lastRow++; // To get the next row 

    for (int i=_lastRow; i<=_lastrow+6; i++) // Set your i value to _lastRow
    {
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = textBox1.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = textBox2.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = textBox3.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = textBox4.Text;
    }
```

Comment: bro dis is nt solving my prblm.......i want to insert different data each time i insert a diffeerent value in textbox........bt it shows the same value six times in a row(i<=6) and repeating the previou one....

Comment: I have made slight changes in code Lets say the last used row in excel sheet is 10 then according to the code your values are written at [11,1][11,2].....[12,1][12,2]...[13,1],[13,2]...[16,1][16,2][16,3][16,4] Now when you run this whole code again next time the last row value you get is 16 and then the loop values are written at [17,1][17,2]... so where are the values overwritten ????

Comment: bt hw cn i insert a new value to the last row without replacing the previous one.......my main concern is dat,,.....??bcoz i m runiing the code it says replace the pprevious file.....i dnt wnt 2 replace the previous file

Comment: I guess it is asking to replace the excel file ...for that you have to save the excel file and then open it again in next time

Comment: yes it is aassking to replace the existing file.....nd wen i replce it ....it shows new data.....nd i dnt replace it....den error occurs...

Comment: @Kyle: You should never use `UsedRange` to find the last row. It's highly unreliable. You might want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)