# inserting texbox data into xls file

Tags: c#

I am getting a problem whilst inserting textbox data into an excel file... the error which keeps showing is given below. What changes should I make in order to successfully insert my data into the `xls` file?

ERROR:
`Property, indexer, or event 'Range' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.get_Range(object, object)'`

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A"+xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = textBox1.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = textBox2.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = textBox3.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = textBox4.Text;
```

The error occurs on the following line:

`int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A"+xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;`

Comment: guys instd of correctng my spells cn nyone crrct my prblm 2...???

Comment: Looks like you had asked same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353980/inserting-multiple-textbox-data-into-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to find row,column of last filled cell . Then you should use `UsedRange`

```
int lastRow = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Row;

int lastCol = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Column;
```

for setting certain value in Your excel for ex. If you want to set value of textBox1 into cell  "B4" then use following code.

```
 xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B4", Type.Missing).Value2 = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: @akk: what are you expecting in  int _lastRow?

Comment: see the linkk u will understnd the prblm bttr..


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353980/inserting-multiple-textbox-data-into-an-excel-file

Comment: Did you try replacing Siddhart's code for last_row with `xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Row;`?

Comment: yes i used his code.....nd the prblm persists in the following code:-

int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A"+xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1 ;

Comment: @akk: If you have got your answer, Please consider accepting answer.