# c# winforms VS2017 linking with excel: error when closing form

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP0gq.png)

This is considered a duplicate post as the exact codes are used for another question (about 5 years ago.).Basically, I get the error **System.NullreferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance on an object'.** for line `xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);`each time I closed the form (see image). Based on the original question: [Inserting multiple textbox data into an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353980/inserting-multiple-textbox-data-into-an-excel-file), I cannot find others having the same problem as me. The code I've used is the same as the link:

```
`using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace Vehicledettry
   {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
      {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.Visible = true;

        // Open a File
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(" C:\\vehicledet.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Plate Number";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Car Model";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Car Brand";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Mileage";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = Plate Number.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = Car Model.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = Car Brand.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = Mileage.Text;

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlexcel);

    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried copying `xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(" C:\\vehicledet.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);` after every button event clicked but the same error kept occurring. Hope that I could get some help. Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of bad practices.  Not hard to get this exception, simply click button3 before clicking button1.

Comment: Hi Hans. When I click button 3, the error will popup and other buttons cannot be pressed. Anyway, button 3 is meant for closing the program so if I pressed it first, all my data will not even be saved (no diff since I cannot even run the program :( ). I'll keep trying.

Comment: Instead of using Excel interop you could use a library like EPPlus to generate `xlsx` files directly. [The API is more or less the same](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Addressing-a-worksheet) but you don't have to worry about installing Excel, closing and properly disposing the COM object.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**(Edited per feedback)** See below. Data in textbox will automatically go into existing excel file of choice. Huge credit to https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c-net for the help

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace exceltry
  {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
       public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
        Excel.Application xlexcel = null;
        Excel._Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
        Excel.Range oRng;

    try
       {
          //start excel and get application object
          oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


          //open existing workbook
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\vehicledet.xlsx");
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

         //Add table headers going cell by cell.
          xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Plate Number";
          xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Car Model";
          xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Car Brand";
          xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Mileage";

         //Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
          xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
          xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment = 
          Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

          // insert text at every last row
            int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Range["A" +    xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;

            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 1] = textBox1.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 2] = textBox2.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 3] = textBox3.Text;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[_lastRow, 4] = textBox4.Text;


            //AutoFit columns A:D.
            oRng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1");
            oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

            //Make sure Excel is not visible and give the user control of Microsoft Excel's lifetime.
            xlexcel.Visible = false;
            xlexcel.UserControl = true;

            //can save update to same file but wont close unless user press x button
            xlWorkbook.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
            xlWorkbook.Close();

            //allow excel to auto close by itself 
            oXL.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);

        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            String errorMessage;
            errorMessage = "Error: ";
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an NRE immediatelly after the button is clicked - `xlexcel` is null. Another serious problem is that it *doesn't* use a `using` block to ensure the COM object is disposed. If an error is thrown, Excel will remain open

Comment: Hi guys. Updated the codings. Thanks all for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have a project also that will send the data into an excel file but not similarly as yours, my data came from a text file and someone on this site help me to figure out how to export the values of my Array in Excel File. In your case maybe, this code will Help.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application exc = new Excel.Application();
exc.Interactive = true;
var excelTemplate = "CompareResult.xlsx"; //Change it with your filename
string FromPath = Path.GetFullPath(excelTemplate); //Get the full path of your excel 
//file.
Excel.Workbook wb = exc.Workbooks.Open(FromPath);
Excel.Worksheet sh = wb.Sheets[1];
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells[xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlUp].Row + 1;
sh.Cells[row, 1].Value2 = textBox1.Text;
sh.Cells[row, 2].Value2 = textBox1.Text;
sh.Cells[row, 3].Value2 = textBox1.Text;
sh.Cells[row, 4].Value2 = textBox1.Text;
wb.Save(); \\Saving the file when changing
wb.Close(); 
exc.Quit();
```